# SQL select distinct last values from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, distinct

I have a table that has a ton of rows (>10K). Most of the rows have duplicate role values associated with the ques_id. I'am new to the sql.
What I am trying to do is select rows by distinct AND latest ques_id added.
Here is my table(tbl_questions) structure.

```
id | ques_id | question       | ans
1  |  2      | HTML stands..  |  3 
2  |  5      | PHP stands..   |  2 
3  |  6      | CSS stands..   |  4 
4  |  6      | CSS stands..   |  4
5  |  5      | PHP stands..   |  2
6  |  6      | CSS stands..   |  4
```

This would be the desired result:

```
id | ques_id | question       | ans
1  |  2      | HTML stands..  |  3 
5  |  5      | PHP stands..   |  2
6  |  6      | CSS stands..   |  4
```

Here are the query I've tried so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ques_id, question, ans FROM tbl_questions
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an other perspective by giving a row number by group.

**Query**

```
select t1.id, t1.ques_id, t1.question, t1.ans from 
(
    select id, ques_id, question, ans, 
    (
        case ques_id when @curA 
        then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        else @curRow := 1 and @curA := ques_id end 
    ) as rn 
    from tbl_questions t, 
    (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
    order by ques_id,id desc 
)t1 
where t1.rn = 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2cef/2)

Comment: It's not 'just another perspective'. This may in fact outperform my own solution!

Answer (score 0):

You want the latest row for each `question`? You can use `NOT EXISTS` to return those rows:

```
SELECT ques_id, question, ans
FROM tbl_questions t1
where not exists (select 1 from tbl_questions t2
                  where t2.ques_id = t1.ques_id
                    and t2.id > t1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM tbl_questions a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT ques_id
            , MAX(id) max_id 
         FROM tbl_questions 
        GROUP 
           BY ques_id
     ) b 
    ON b.max_id = a.id;
```

Comment: @b0s3 I wasn't suggesting that you should delete your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id DESC),',',1) AS i_d, 
ques_id, 
question,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ans ORDER BY id DESC),',',1) AS Answer 
FROM tbl_questions 
GROUP BY ques_id
```

Output

```
i_d |ques_id | question       | Answer
1    2      HTML stands..       3
5    5      PHP stands..        2
6    6      CSS stands..        4
```

Comment: @Strawberry:Thanks for pointing that. And I have edited my code. Please check it